# perl command not found

Tags: c, linux, perl, bash

I have a c code and I want take my code a perl command as argument like this:

```
./code ‫'‪'perl -e 'print "A"x202;'"cat file‬‬
"cat file": command not found
```

I have cat command in my machine.
could you possibly tell me what the problem is?
thank you in advance

Comment: Injection error. You're trying to nest single quotes...

Comment: thank you.there is no error but the result is not what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you want to use the `cat` command in your case, however, as @ikegami said, you are nesting quotes. In your perl part, use `q{}` or `qq[]` to get single or double quotes, and circumvent actually typing them out -- what you use as a delimiter is free with `q` and `qq`

use double quotes for your perl script if you can, so what you get is

```
./code 'perl -e " use q<> or qq++ here "'
```

Answer (score -1):

It could be that your path is not correctly set inside your code.
I would advice to pass the full cat command path.

You can get the full path of the cat command by typing:

```
which cat
```

In my machine the cat command is located in /bin directory, therefore I would give:

```
./code ‫'‪'perl -e 'print "A"x202;'"/bin/cat file‬‬
```

Comment: sorry, see ikegami's comment above for the real reason. This has nothing to do with `cat` not being available.